# How can this equation make sense?

Tags: formation-of-numbers

Think a bit creatively and tell me why is this equation correct
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we assume that

> X is 10 (Roman Numeral),
>
> then, the equation becomes $\frac{711018}{7182}$ = $\frac{71082}{718}$ = $99$

Answer (score 0):

X could be represented as

> $* 0 *$,  thus creating the equation:
>  $\frac{71*0*18}{7182} = \frac{7*0*82}{718}$

or

> ($\frac{0}{7182} = \frac{0}{718}) = (0 = 0)$